# name is not defined on visual studio

Tags: python

I'm using Visual Studio to run py file. I'm very new to OOP, so I'm having a difficulty to debug this issue. It says name "mng" is not defined and "Manager" object has no attribute "salary". How should I fix this issue?

```
class Employee:
    MIN_SALARY = 30000
    def __init__(self, name, salary=MIN_SALARY):
        self.name = name
        if self.salary >= Employee.MIN_SALARY:
            self.salary = Employee.salary
        else:
            self.salary = Employee.MIN_SALARY

    def give_raise(self, amount):
        self.salary += amount

class Manager(Employee):
    def display(self):
        return print("Manager", self.name)

mng = Manager("Debbie Lashko", 86500)
print(mng.name)
mng.display()

>>> mng = Manager("Debbie Lashko", 86500)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __init__
AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'salary'
>>> print(mng.name)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'mng' is not defined
>>> mng.display()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'mng' is not defined
```

Comment: Please post the full error message and correct the indentation of your code example.

Comment: Besides the indentation issue here, you're never assigning salary in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with this code.
But, your error could be solve with:

```
class Employee:
    MIN_SALARY = 30000

    def __init__(self, name, salary=MIN_SALARY):
        self.name = name

        if salary >= Employee.MIN_SALARY:
```

`self.salary` was not declare before the comparison. So, manager do not have `self.salary` yet. Use just `salary` in the if statement

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign something to an attribute before you can use it. Just change your logic a bit.

```
    def __init__(self, name, salary=MIN_SALARY):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        if self.salary < Employee.MIN_SALARY:
            self.salary = Employee.MIN_SALARY
```

Or you could use a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

```
    def __init__(self, name, salary=MIN_SALARY):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary if salary >= Employee.MIN_SALARY else Employee.MIN_SALARY
```

Comment: @Mike - making that change to `__init__` works for me.